# How Standard CAN win the bus access in Arbitration with EXT CAN?

Tags: can-bus

I read some documents and all of them say that the Std CAN have higher priority than the Ext CAN because the SRR bit is always Recessive in EXT CAN when they have the same ID, but from my understanding it depends.

https://copperhilltech.com/blog/controller-area-network-can-bus-tutorial-extended-can-protocol/

To simplify, let's say we have message ID 0x1(Std CAN) and 0x1(Ext CAN) sending simultaneously on the same bus.
The arbitration field of the Std CAN be compared to Ext CAN should be like this:

Std CAN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 *1* **0** (The bold bit is RTR)

Ext CAN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 *0* **1 1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 **0** (The bold bits are SRR, IDE and RTR)

At the 11th bit, The node that sends Std CAN is sending 1 (Recessive bit), and the node that sends Ext CAN is sending 0 (Dominant bit), so the Ext CAN wins the bus access and the node that sends Std CAN switch to listen mode and not sending anything after that, so the SRR and IDE bits never be reached to decide the message is Ext CAN or Std CAN.

Is my above understanding correct?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an 29 bit frame with RTR set has higher priority than an 11 bit frame without RTR, given the first 11 bits of the identifiers are identical. So saying that standard frames have higher priority than extended is a simplification.

RTR frames is a bit of an oddball case overall, as they may also have varied length in the DLC area even though there's no data at all in the frame.

Answer (score 0):

The SRR Field at the 11th position is deliberately added to the extended CAN and is always recessive so that CAN standard messages always have higher priority over Extended CAN

Taking example of your above message format.
Std CAN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 (When the message is a RTR , 11th bit is set as 1)

Ext CAN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 (This is wrong as SRR is always recessive and will be 1)

CorrectExt CAN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0